# User's name and email address is incorrect for the user, but correct in User Profile Services and everywhere else

Tags: user-profile

We have a user who was added to the Active Directory incorrectly (wrong first name). This was quickly changed in the AD and this change replicated through to SharePoint. When I look for this person in people picker, user profile, ForeFront, anywhere, I see the updated name.

However, whenever the user accesses SharePoint, he sees the original incorrect name, and also an invalid email address (containing a space).  He's using the same account name, so it's not another account lurking somewhere.

I have tried to delete the profile from the User Profile service, and his profile was recreated at the next sync as expected, but the user is still seeing the wrong information.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - this has been going around for weeks now and I've just not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The info is probably incorrect because of the hidden user list in each site collection (/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx after the root site URL). This sometimes doesn't update even tho UPS does.

To fix, you need to manually remove the entry for the user from the hidden list, then when they access it again a fresh entry will be added.

Use the Remove-SPUser command to remove them (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607894.aspx) - remember if you're using Claims Based Auth you need to use that format (use Get-SPUser to find out the exact value).

If it needs to be done over multiple site collections, then use Get-SPSite then a for..each loop to go through each of them and remove the user entry.

Comment: @Darryl Ashton You can also refer this article for more detail on Hidden User Information List- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marj/2016/03/14/what-is-hidden-user-information-userinfo-list-in-sharepoint-20102013-and-how-to-fix-when-it-causes-a-site-collection-to-show-old-user-metadata-properties-in-people-picker-control-or-in-a-person-or/

Comment: Thanks for that. I used Remove-SPUser as directed, and the user's name in the top right of the person.aspx page was corrected, but the name in the main body of person.aspx was still the incorrect name. When the user checked again ten minutes later, the name in the top-right was incorrect again. The name in UPS is still correct.

Comment: Try doing Remove-SPUser (on every site collection in every web app), then delete the entry for the user in the profile store, then get them to access again. If that doesn't work I'm not really sure.